# Cannot open Pinta on my Ubuntu 16:04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, mono

I tried purging the application and installing again, but it didn't work.

When I tried `apt-get clean` after removing Pinta again, here is the output:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-icon-theme libglib2.0-cil libgtk2.0-cil libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libglib2.0-cil (2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1) ...
/usr/bin/gacutil: 2: exec: /usr/bin/mono: not found
W: removing assembly:  failed!
sh: 1: /usr/bin/mono: not found
Use of uninitialized value $_ in scalar chomp at /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono line 275.
Use of uninitialized value $fullname in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono line 225.
/usr/bin/gacutil: 2: exec: /usr/bin/mono: not found
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libglib2.0-cil/policy.2.8.glib-sharp.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.2.8.glib-sharp with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-cil (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-cil:
 libgtk2.0-cil depends on libglib2.0-cil (= 2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1); however:
  Package libglib2.0-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgtk2.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up libmono-addins0.2-cil (1.0+git20130406.adcd75b-4) ...
* Installing 18 assemblies from libmono-addins0.2-cil into Mono
sh: 1: /usr/bin/mono: not found
Use of uninitialized value $_ in scalar chomp at /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono line 275.
Use of uninitialized value $fullname in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono line 225.
/usr/bin/gacutil: 2: exec: /usr/bin/mono: not found
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/Mono.Addins-0.2/Mono.Addins.dll failed
E: Installation of libmono-addins0.2-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
dpkg: error processing package libmono-addins0.2-cil (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil:
 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil depends on libglib2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libglib2.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil depends on libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil depends on libmono-addins0.2-cil (>= 1.0); however:
  Package libmono-addins0.2-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-cil
 libgtk2.0-cil
 libmono-addins0.2-cil
 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mono-runtime` gave me the following:

```
Removing libgtk2.0-cil (2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1) ...
E: File does not exist: /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.10.atk-sharp.installcligac
dpkg: error processing package libgtk2.0-cil (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing libglib2.0-cil (2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1) ...
E: File does not exist: /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.8.glib-sharp.installcligac
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-cil (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgtk2.0-cil
 libglib2.0-cil
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil`:

```
libgtk2.0-cil:
  Installed: 2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1
  Candidate: 2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1
  Version table:
 *** 2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1 500
        500 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.12.10-6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libglib2.0-cil:
  Installed: 2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1
  Candidate: 2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1
  Version table:
 *** 2.12.45-0xamarin17+ubuntu1604b1 500
        500 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.12.10-6 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mono-runtime` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @N0rbert Updted my description

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil`. If it fails then recreate these files manually by`sudo touch /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.10.atk-sharp.installcligac ; sudo touch /usr/share/cli-common/packages.d/policy.2.8.glib-sharp.installcligac` and retry .

Comment: @N0rbert I had to use the touch command to create those files, but still the suggested apt-get gives me this error   "E: Internal Error, No file name for libglib2.0-cil:amd64"

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert updated the question, please have a look

Comment: Do you use Mono repository to develop some Mono applications in MonoDevelop? Also try `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-cil=2.12.10-6 libglib2.0-cil=2.12.10-6`.

Comment: @N0rbert I installed mono earlier, but have uninstalled it some time ago. Here's the result of the above command https://pastebin.com/QqrsJWHs

Comment: Any idea what could be wrong with my system?

Comment: It looks like some dependencies are not correctly satisfied. Could you please add the output of `dpkg -l | grep xamarin` to the pastebin too? Then we can remove this mono-project repository and start over.

Comment: @N0rbert had to create a new paste for this https://pastebin.com/aWrZN2Lt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107700/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-harsha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During chat session we did the following.

As there were problems with packages from Xamarin repository we carefully removed its packages from the system with:

```bsh
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list ~
sudo dpkg -P --force-all $(dpkg -l | grep xamarin | awk '{print $2}')
```

Then ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get check
```

And then we removed Pinta repository which does not publish packages for xenial:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
```

And everything is OK after this.

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much